# What does this 'replace' line do in python?

Tags: python, replace

data = { k.replace("-", "_"): None for k in fields }

what does it really means?

Comment: What did you see when you inspected `fields` and `data`? would could you conclude?

Comment: Theoretically: we have no idea because we cannot know what `k` is. Practically: it replaces the string - with _ . Honestly: what is there possibly to not understand about this?

Answer (score 1):

Here your `fields` variable must be an **iterable** (`list`, `tuple`, ...) of `str`, therefore `k` must be a `str` and you want to `replace` every `-` to `_`

Answer (score 0):

Given a list called fields, it creates a dict with each key being each element of fields (with "-" replaced with "_") and each value being None.

```
fields = ["a", "b", "c-d"]
data = { k.replace("-", "_"): None for k in fields }
print(data)
```

`{'a': None, 'b': None, 'c_d': None}`